# Python - Tensorflow, binary classification, always predicting 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am just starting out with Tensorflow, trying to create a classic neural net for binary classification.

```
# Loading Dependencies

import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

seed = 1234
tf.set_random_seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)

# Load and Split data
data = pd.read_json(file)
X = data["X"]
y = data["y"]
X = X.astype(np.float32)
y = y.astype(np.float32)

X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3)

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], -1).T
y_train = y_train.values.reshape((1, y_train.shape[0]))
X_valid = X_valid.reshape(X_valid.shape[0], -1).T
y_valid = y_valid.values.reshape((1, y_valid.shape[0]))

print("X Train: ", X_train.shape)
print("y Train: ", y_train.shape)
print("X Dev: ", X_valid.shape)
print("y Dev: ", y_valid.shape)
```

X Train:  (16875, 1122) 
y Train:  (1, 1122) 
X Dev:  (16875, 482) 
y Dev:  (1, 482)

The training data contains float numbers, while the labels are just 0 or 1. However, these are also converted to float because I had some issues in the past.

Initializing the parameters

```
def initialize_parameters(layer_dimensions):
    tf.set_random_seed(seed)
    layers_count = len(layer_dimensions)
    parameters = {}

    for layer in range(1, layers_count):
        parameters['W' + str(layer)] = tf.get_variable('W' + str(layer), 
                                                   [layer_dimensions[layer], layer_dimensions[layer - 1]], 
                                                   initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed = seed))

        parameters['b' + str(layer)] = tf.get_variable('b' + str(layer), 
                                                   [layer_dimensions[layer], 1], 
                                                   initializer = tf.zeros_initializer())

    return parameters
```

Shapes are: 
W1 - (50, 16875) 
W2 - (25, 50) 
W3 - (10, 25) 
W4 - (5, 10) 
W5 - (1, 5) 
b1 - (50, 1) 
b2 - (25, 1) 
b3 - (10, 1) 
b4 - (5, 1) 
b5 - (1, 1)

I am specifying the number and the dimension of each layer when I am calling the model (see below)

Forward Propagation

```
def forward_propagation(X, parameters):
    parameters_count = len(parameters) // 2 
    A = X

    for layer in range(1, parameters_count):
        W = parameters['W' + str(layer)]
        b = parameters['b' + str(layer)]

        Z = tf.add(tf.matmul(W, A), b)
        A = tf.nn.relu(Z)

    W = parameters['W' + str(parameters_count)]
    b = parameters['b' + str(parameters_count)]

    Z = tf.add(tf.matmul(W, A), b)

    return Z
```

Compute the cost (I am using the sigmoid function since we are dealing with binary classification)

```
def compute_cost(Z, Y):    
    logits = tf.transpose(Z)
    labels = tf.transpose(Y)

    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits, labels = labels))
    return cost
```

Putting it together

```
def model(X_train, y_train, X_valid, y_valid, layer_dimensions, alpha = 0.0001, epochs = 10):

    ops.reset_default_graph()
    tf.set_random_seed(seed)

    (x_rows, m) = X_train.shape
    y_rows = y_train.shape[0]

    costs = []

    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(x_rows, None), name="X")
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(y_rows, None), name="y")

    parameters = initialize_parameters(layer_dimensions)
    Z = forward_propagation(X, parameters)
    cost = compute_cost(Z, y)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = alpha).minimize(cost)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            _ , epoch_cost = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: X_train, y: y_train})
            print ("Cost after epoch %i: %f" % (epoch + 1, epoch_cost))
            costs.append(epoch_cost)

        parameters = sess.run(parameters)

        correct_predictions = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Z), tf.argmax(y))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predictions, "float"))

        print ("Train Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({X: X_train, y: y_train}))
        print ("Test Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({X: X_valid, y: y_valid}))

        return parameters
```

Now when I try to train my model it appears to reaches an optimum from the second epoch and the cost changes very little from that point on

```
parameters = model(X_train, y_train, X_valid, y_valid, [X_train.shape[0], 50, 25, 10, 5, 1])
```

Cost after epoch 1: 8.758244 
Cost after epoch 2: 0.693096 
Cost after epoch 3: 0.692992 
Cost after epoch 4: 0.692737 
Cost after epoch 5: 0.697333 
Cost after epoch 6: 0.693062 
Cost after epoch 7: 0.693151 
Cost after epoch 8: 0.693152 
Cost after epoch 9: 0.693152 
Cost after epoch 10: 0.693155

Now for the predictions

```
def predict(X, parameters):
    parameters_count = len(parameters) // 2 
    params = {}

    for layer in range(1, parameters_count + 1):
        params['W' + str(layer)] = tf.convert_to_tensor(parameters['W' + str(layer)])
        params['b' + str(layer)] = tf.convert_to_tensor(parameters['b' + str(layer)])

    (x_columns, x_rows) = X.shape
    X_test = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(x_columns, x_rows))

    Z = forward_propagation(X_test, params)
    p = tf.argmax(Z)

    sess = tf.Session()
    prediction = sess.run(p, feed_dict = {X_test: X})

    return prediction
```

However, this will predict 0 in every case..

```
predictions = predict(X_valid, parameters)
predictions
```

array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0....

Comment: What percentage of your actual labels are 0?  It's possible that everything is working fine.  However, since ReLUs are subject to the dying ReLU problem, you might try using something like leaky ReLUs instead.  Also, you might try using just a single layer and seeing if that gives you different results.

Comment: It turns out you were right. My ReLU functions were indeed dying and all my features ended up being 0 in the end. I switched to leaky ReLUs and starting seeing some results. Thanks for the tip @Stephen

Answer (score 0):

```
X Train: (16875, 1122)
```

You have 16875 features for each sample, but only 1122 train data.
I think this may be not enough.

The sample code in tensorflow get-started only takes 784 features.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])
```

> The MNIST data is split into three parts: 55,000 data points of training data (mnist.train), 10,000 points of test data (mnist.test), and 5,000 points of validation data (mnist.validation). This split is very important: it's essential in machine learning that we have separate data which we don't learn from so that we can make sure that what we've learned actually generalizes!
>   https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners

Comment: I agree that more data would be helpful, but this is not the issue. I should be able to get at least some sort of predictions, even if they are not that accurate.

I also have a test set which is not loaded in the code I posted, but the results are the same

Comment: Ok, what is outputs for Z?

    Z = forward_propagation(X_test, params)
    p = tf.argmax(Z)

    sess = tf.Session()
    prediction = sess.run(p, feed_dict = {X_test: X})